# Cannot reauthenticate in iOS Game Center

Tags: ios, authentication, xamarin.ios, xamarin, game-center

Im facing a very strange problem with GameCenter in iOS + Xamarin iOS.

When an user cancels the authentication process with GameCenter, if I set again the AuthenticateHandler it does nothing, the handler is never fired, except if I send the app to background and then restore it.

¿Is this normal behavior or is there any way to do this to work?

Is very annoying that you can't authenticate if you press the cancel option by mistake.

Here is my authentication code:

```
    if (!GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated) 
    {
            GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = 
            (UIViewController cont, NSError Err) => {

                if (cont != null)
                    OpenGLViewController.CurrentController.
                    PresentViewController (cont, true, null);
                else if (GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated) {
                    //Authenticated user
                } else {
                    //Error
                }
            };

    } else {
                   //Authenticated user
    }
```